# Angular JS Unit Testing using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

```
I have a factory service as below
```

FamilyService.js

(function(){
    'use strict';

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('ABC', FamilyService);

FamilyService.$inject = ['DEF'];
function FamilyService(DEF) {


function returnTrue() {
    var a="true";

}       

}
```

}());

```
    I want to call returnTrue method in My test case

 **TestFamilyService.js**
```

describe('testing my_controller.my_function', function () {
      var mockedFactory, $rootScope, $controller;

```
  beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
    mockedFactory = {
      save: jasmine.createSpy()
    };

    $provide.value('ABC', mockedFactory);
  }));




  it('should call the save function', function() {

    expect(mockedFactory.returnTrue()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});



     **specrunner.html**


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.4.1</title>

      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">

      <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/angular-mocks.js"></script>


      <!-- include source files here... -->
      <script src="src/Player.js"></script>
      <script src="src/webapp/Mock.js"></script>
      <script src="src/webapp/FamilyService.js"></script>




      <!-- include spec files here... -->

      <script src="spec/TestFamilyService.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When i run specrunner.html in the browser it displays

Error: No module: app

TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'returnTrue': object is null or undefined

Please Tel me whats wrong here?

Comment: in which js file do you initialize the app module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FamilyService.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('ABC', FamilyService);
```

you are creating a factory for the **existing module** `app`, but if the module **doesn't exist** you need to write

```
angular.module('app',[]).factory('ABC', FamilyService);
```

In your case just create a **new file**, where the angular module gets created

```
angular.module('app',[]);
```

**UPDATE**

Just include the dependencies of your module in the html

```
 <script src="lib/angular-sanititze/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

If you want to mock these modules, you can do something like

```
beforeEach(function() {
       angular.module('second',[]);
}
```

But in the case that you are using some methods of the third party library, you need to mock these methods as well.

Comment: you want me to add angular.module('app',[]);  line to a separate file

Comment: when i asked you, where your module declaration is, you answered that it is in FamilyService.js, but thats not a module declaration. Its a usage of the module. You need to define the module first. And in common cases you do that in a separate file. See https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md for example

Comment: Yea it was defined in a separate file...That error got resolved after adding that js while contained module declaration but it depends on 5 more modules..that modules names are thrown as not found now ...example app module needs ngSanitize , ui-bootstrap etc

Comment: you need to mock these dependencies or include the files in your test-config

Comment: I mocked the module in beforeeach() but is there any other ways to mock our modules and factory services

Comment: just add the dependencies of ngSanititze etc to your jasmine config

Comment: Am not Clear Tobias Timm

Comment: UnderStood Timm....If am using an Existing module then i have to specify  the dependent modules in my specs..right